# PHP template inclusion outside global scope

Tags: php, frameworks

I'm currently creating a framework, just for the sake of a personal study-project, i.e. to be able to evaluate php-frameworks in general futurewise. As I'm starting to build up more appreciation for some of the frameworks, especially about the way they designed their modules and made them available in 'their scope', during the development of this project I'm also baffled as to why almost all framework-developers include the (view)templates inside the scope of their classes.

Perhaps there are some developers roaming these boards that are able to be constructive about it.

An example (which for the sake of clarity is very much oversimplified).

Why do this...

```
<?php

class TemplateInc {

    public $template;

    public function __construct($page) {

        $this->template = $page;
    }

    public function render() {

        require_once $this->template;
    }
}

$template_include = new TemplateInc('mypage.html');
$template_include->render();

?>
```

...when its also possible to do it like this, at the same time being able to also use the global-scope variables in the templates (if appropriate) ?

```
<?php

class TemplateName {

    public $template;

    public function __construct($page) {

        $this->template = $page;
    }

    public function getTemplate() {

        return $this->template;
    }
}

$templatename = new TemplateName('mypage.html');
require_once $templatename->getTemplate();

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Usually the template class would also make additional values available to the template. E.g.:

```
public function render(array $vars) {
    extract($vars);
    require $this->template;
}
```

Or the template could make use of `$this->..` to access other methods/objects/values/services which are part of the class. None of this is possible if you do the `require` outside of the class. Then *only* global variables are available to the template, of which you hopefully don't have any (don't use `global`). Doing all this inside a method allows you do to something like `extract($vars)` without cluttering the global scope.

Further, instead of a nicely self-contained call to `$template->render()`, you now need to do `require $template->render()`, which kind of negates the point of writing a class in the first place; the caller is still doing all the work and the class itself basically doesn't (can't) do anything.

Comment: I could be mistaking but imho it all depends on the overal design. Instead of using the class solely to include the template from within the class and to be able to (merely) feed it its local scope ($this) one would still be able to do just that via $template->getvars() but would also be able to feed it vars from the global scope. The usefullness and encapsulation by using the (view)class like this would/could/should remain the same while the template benefits from the global scope as well.

Comment: Comment part 2 - Everything else in a possible MVC or MVP setup could or would still have the same responsibilities as all results from requests could still end up in the template through the $view->getResult(), so it would maintain the MVC/MVP principles. The only thing that would be different would be the location of inclusion. It would sorta break tradition by 'defying' the general idea that templates need to be included inside the local (class)scope but the general script would still conform to OOP principles.

Comment: Basically you're telling me you want to use global scoping for... pretty much everything. Well, with that design approach, there's not a lot of use talking about OOP at all. If your template does rely on `$template->` to access data, you've got all the problems associated with global variables. Namely that you must name your template object `$template` and can never rename it, and you can't have two instances of it at the same time, because there can only be one global variable with that name. Which is... insane, for anything but the most trivial applications.

Comment: Yes that would make a lot of sense but for my particular design only a single instance is needed which represents all the template files in no particular order though covers every request all the same. My particular design doesnt break the OOP rules, just bends them in order to be able to load some (language)variables from the global scope. And while this could easily translate into bad practices i.e. procedural methods it doesnt as long as the programmer is disciplined enough to conform using objects for everything else. It is interesting though to see where this little experiment leads to.

Comment: Few days past I'd have to admit my wrong deceze, exposing the template to the global scope defies the principle of encapsulation just a tad too much so I refactored it back to total encapsulation ( $view->render() ). Thanks for your input/criticism. Regards